# When update Xcode, error in Titanium Appcelerator "Failed to parse app's Info.plist"

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

When i update Xcode the error in Titanium Appcelerator "Failed to parse app's Info.plist". I am unable to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode) at the documentation.

Xcode 8 is only supported when using TiSDK 5.5.0 or higher. If you don't want to compile with that  version, you should downgrade xcode to get it to work again.

Comment: In addition to that, make sure that you have both Titanium SDK 5.5.0+ and Titanium CLI 5.5.0+. You can update by using "appc setup" in the CLI or search for updates in the Appcelerator Studio.